# Is it possible to select the first line of a UILabel?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uilabel

I have a UILabel with the parameter numberOfLines set to 2. I would like to make 2 UIlabels from this one, the first one would be the first line and the second will be the second line. Is there any way to make it?

Comment: The text on the label is still saved as one string. The text rendered on each line is decided by the Apple UI framework based on some graphics stuff. `numberOfLines` is the max number of lines to use, not something guaranteed to split your label text into two discrete units.

Answer (score 2):

In this solution, I've assumed that you have `UILabel` with 2 line at least, and there is a `\n` character at the end of the first line.

```
UILabel *lbl = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:2];

NSString *firstString;
NSString *secondString;

NSRange foundRange = [lbl.text rangeOfString:@"\n"];
if (foundRange.location != NSNotFound)
{
    foundRange.length = foundRange.location + 1;
    foundRange.location = 0;
    firstString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[lbl.text substringWithRange:foundRange]];
    secondString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[lbl.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:foundRange withString:@""]];

    NSLog(@"first line = %@", firstString);
    NSLog(@"second line = %@", secondString);
    [firstString release];
    [secondString release];
}
```